# Turtlesim Pose theta

Tags: ros, pose, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to get the theta (or any) float variable from the turtlesim.msg Pose, and not having any luck.

I've been trying things like;

subscribing directly to theta, rospy.Subscriber("turtle1/pose", turtlesim.msg.Pose('theta'))

or by subscribing to pose and pulling theta out of the pose msg

Thanks for any help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53298/turtlesim-pose-theta/) by [imageryeel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3979/imageryeel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Subscribing to the pose and retrieving values from the message is the way to do it and does work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1